# Slim Framework - Class 'Slim\\Middleware' not found

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to create a custom middleware class and can't seem to call `extend \Slim\Middleware` because it's not found.

This is my index.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);

// Register middleware
require __DIR__ . '/../src/middleware.php';

// Run app
$app->run();
```

This is my middleware.php

```
<?php
require_once("tester_auth.php");

$app->add(new TestAuth());
```

This is my tester_auth.php which is the  custom middleware file

```
<?php
use Slim\Middleware;

class TestAuth extends \Slim\Middleware {

    public function __construct() {
        //Define the urls that you want to exclude from Authentication, aka public urls     
        $this->whiteList = array('\/login');
    }

    public function deny_access() {
        $res = $this->app->response();
        $res->status(401);
    }

    public function isPublicUrl($url) {
        $patterns_flattened = implode('|', $this->whiteList);
        $matches = null;
        preg_match('/' . $patterns_flattened . '/', $url, $matches);
        return (count($matches) > 0);
    }

    public function call() {
        //Get the token sent from jquery
        $tokenAuth = $this->app->request->headers->get('Authorization');
        //We can check if the url requested is public or protected
        if ($this->isPublicUrl($this->app->request->getPathInfo())) {
            //if public, then we just call the next middleware and continue execution normally
            $this->next->call();
        } else {
            $this->deny_access(); 
        }
    }
}
```

It successfully gets to my TestAuth but gives me the error `Class 'Slim\\Middleware' not found in /var/www/html/src/tester_auth.php on line 6` ...

Edit:

At first,  I was having this issue because my composer.json didn't have middleware installed but I have since updated it and it's there now but still having the same issue..

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "slim/slim": "^3.8",
        "slim/php-view": "^2.0",
        "slim/middleware": "*",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.17"
    }
```

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @JeremyHarris i did `php composer.phar dump-autoload` but the same issue is happening

Comment: You are mixing Slim 2 and Slim 3 code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your HTTP server (ngixn, PHP web server,..) in case it caches some PHP.

BTW, [slim/middleware](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Middleware) is for Slim 2.*, but you are using 3.*.